# How to return HTTP 400 response in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to return a HTTP 400 response from my django view function if the request GET data is invalid and cannot be parsed.

How do I do this? There does not seem to be a corresponding `Exception` class like there is for 404:

```
raise Http404
```

Comment: Return a HttpResponseBadRequest : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseBadRequest You can create an Exception subclass like Http404 to have your own Http400 exception.

Comment: Thanks, you could put it in an answer :)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From my previous comment :

You can return a [HttpResponseBadRequest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseBadRequest)

Also, you can create an Exception subclass like Http404 to have your own Http400 exception.

Comment: Can you show how to create an Exception subclass? Django `BaseHandler` looks for the `Http404` type specifically and always uses status code 404, I can't see a clean way of wiring your own exception and status code in there

Answer (score 30):

You can do the following:

```
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation
raise SuspiciousOperation("Invalid request; see documentation for correct paramaters")
```

SuspiciousOperation is mapped to a 400 response around line 207 of https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/handlers/base.py

Comment: This mapping is also listed in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/views/#the-400-bad-request-view).

Comment: Neither SuspiciousOperation nor 400 are in the code you linked to. I guess it's changed.

Answer (score 22):

If you're using the Django Rest Framework, you have two ways of raising a 400 response in a view:

```python
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError, ParseError

raise ValidationError

# or 
raise ParseError
```

Comment: You can also use `raise ValidationError("some message")` to render data with the response.

Comment: Also, if you want to reffer to a specific field: `raise ValidationError({"some_field": "some error"})`

Answer (score 18):

Since Django 3.2, you can also raise a `BadRequest` exception:

```
from django.core.exceptions import BadRequest

raise BadRequest('Invalid request.')
```

This may be better in some cases than `SuspiciousOperation` mentioned in another answer, as it does not log a security event; see the [doc on exceptions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/exceptions/).